# Visa cancellation

Tags: australian-citizens

If someone is leaving in Australia and their Visa got rejected just because someone complained about them in embassy 
What will be the solution to apply  for the Visa again

Comment: Is the "someone" an Australian citizen? Which country's visa are you talking about? Please give more details or your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Uceibila Please don't edit posts that are on hold unless your edit actually fixes the reason they're on hold. The first time (and _only_ the first time) an on-hold post is edited, it is automatically nominated for reopening. This is designed to help the post get reopened once the problems with it are fixed. When you edit without fixing the problems, you make it much harder for the post to be reopened in the future because, when the asker fixes the problems, the post won't be automatically nominated for reopening, so probably nobody will notice that it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Visa officials in countries like Australia don't change their decision just because somebody **complains** about an applicant.

They might change their decision if somebody **gives them information** about the applicant, new information they did not have before. But only if the information checks out, not if somebody makes wild, unsubstantiated claims. So if the information caused the visa officials to cancel a visa, they probably believe that the applicant lied to them.

So, was the application truthful?